# Alternative for Selenium Webdriver in integration tests

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver

In my Rails app I have a hidden little form, which is made visible by clicking a button. This is done with some jQuery "hide" and "show" commands, the form itself is pretty much standard stuff.

To test this I can use Selenium Webdriver, but it seems a bit heavy to startup a Firefox browser only for clicking that button with jQuery functionality. Are there any alternatives to do this more lean and simple?

Edit: there is a nice Railscast about using PhantomJS together with Rails and rspec: http://railscasts.com/episodes/391-testing-javascript-with-phantomjs

Comment: If you used a framework, you could test the js component in isolation. Hard to find an alternative otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You coud take a look on Webdriver but with the [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) - which supports headless testing.
I haven't use it by myself but I've heard that's a good option if you don't need/want fire up the whole browser.
I think you need [Ghost Driver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) to bind it with the Webdriver but you woud need check that.